# Github Pages Domain name auto replaced by Personal Domain Name

Tags: dns, github-pages

Recently I noticed an issue in my Github pages. When I try to deploy a site on GitHub pages the default *{github_username}.github.io* got replaced with my personal domain name automatically. Is there any way to get the default GitHub pages domain name?

N.B. I bought my personal domain name from **Namecheap** using **GitHub student developer pack** Maybe that's why GitHub automatically replaces the default domain one

[image: Deploying Website]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not automatic. It's because you have a CNAME file [here](https://github.com/SifatIbna/SifatIbna.github.io/blob/main/CNAME). Delete this file & your problem should be solved. Also ensure that the custom domain field is empty in the GitHub pages setting (in your repo).

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have already set a custom domain, it will always redirect to your domain from the default xxx.github.io domain.

You need to remove the custom domain binding from the pages settings page, and remove the `CNAME` file at the root of the repository.
Thus removing CNAME record from DNS is not necessary.

For more information about github pages custom domain, see the [article](https://www.daxiaju.net/2023/11/30/github-pages-custom-domain/) and the [official document](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site).